# React js how to get OneSignal additional data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onesignal

I want to get additional data when I clicked the push notification. I found the this data in indexedDb but cannot get this data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb4LC.png)

```
{url: 'http://localhost:3000', data: {…}, timestamp: 1641677102449}
 data:
 content: "index"
 data: {orgId: '18'}
 heading: "index"
 icon: undefined
 id: "my_id"
 timestamp: 1641677102449
 url: "http://localhost:3000"
```

I need this object which is in indexedDb